# SQLAlchemy model hybrid property extract is not returning value but object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy model like the following.

```
class ElUsage(Base):
    recid = Column(Integer(),primary_key=True)
    date_of_usage = Column(DATE())
    total_units = Column(Float(precision=5))
```

In this model, I am trying to include a hybrid property for finding the day number like the following.

```
@hybrid_property
def day_type(self):
    is_week_day = 1
    week_day = extract('isodow',self.date_of_usage)

    return week_day
```

After the day number is acquired, I will apply the following rule:
if the day number is greater than 5, return one else 0.
As of now, it is returning an Extract object. Is there a way we can get value from the extract function? Value like 5 or 1 ?

DB is - PostgreSQL

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I got this resolved. The missing piece was `expression`.

Here is the revised `hybridproperty' and` expression'

```
@hybrid_property
    def day_type(self):
        is_week_day = 1
        week_day = self.usage_date.isocalendar()[2]
        print(week_day)
        
        if week_day > 5:
              is_week_day = 0
        
        return week_day
    
    @day_type.expression
    def day_type(cls):
        from sqlalchemy import true
        
        return case([(sal.extract('isodow',cls.usage_date).__gt__(5), 1),],
                    else_ = 0)
```